# How to run Cucumber scenario?

Tags: cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-java

`I can't run the Cucumber scenario from example.feature.`

`When I click on CucumberTestRunner.java everything is fine and the tests pass..`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Nes.png)

`But as soon as I click on the scenario, everything breaks`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky1iQ.png)

Here are my dependencies in gradle

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE0WR.png)

[Here are my scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtgQW.png)

Comment: Using screenshots to share your code isn't good. Fortunately your problem isn't in the code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the run button in a scenario, instead of using the `cucumber-junit-engine`, IDEA uses the `io.cucumber.core.cli` to run your features.

IDEA unfortunately tries to guess which packages might have step definitions. And sometimes it guesses incorrectly.

You can change the run configuration and clear out the "Glue" field.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243074/Do-not-suggest-glue-packages-for-Cucumber-v6.0.0